# MVC DropDownListFor Change value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have taken a crack at writing the JavaScript to handle the changing of a DropDownListFor but its wrong. I don't want to submit the form on the change. I want to select a value from the DropDownList, show the list has been changed but not submit the form as the form still has additional controls to be filled in. How do I do this with JavaScript of jQuery? Does it have to do a Postback?

Here is the JavaScript code I wrote and the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#DropDownListForId').change(function () {
            $('form#myForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px;">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CurrentPub)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CurrentPub)
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="form-holder">
        @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {id = "myForm"}))
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label>UI Element:</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedUIItem, Model.UIItems, new {@id = "DropDownListForId"})
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UseWholeMarkup)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.UseWholeMarkup)
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                @Html.LabelFor(m =>  m.HTMLMarkupCode)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.HTMLMarkupCode, new { rows = "10", cols = "100" })
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the ViewModel:

```
public class UIItemsViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Current Pub: ")]
        public string CurrentPub { get; set; }

        // DropDownList
        public string SelectedUIItem { get; set; }
        // public IEnumerable<string> SelectedUIItem { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UIItems { get; set; }

        // Checkbox
        [DisplayName("Use Whole Markup ")]
        public bool UseWholeMarkup { get; set; }

        // Text Area - Whole Markup
        [Display(Name = "HTML Markup Code: ")]
        public string HTMLMarkupCode { get; set; }

        public string HeaderText { get; set; }
        public string HeaderFColor { get; set; }
        public string HeaderBColor { get; set; }
        public string LogoURL { get; set; }
        public string FooterFColor { get; set; }
        public string FooterText { get; set; }
        public string FooterBColor { get; set; }
        public string BodyText { get; set; }
        public string BodyFColor { get; set; }
        public string BodyBColor { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to actually do in the `change` event (display a message?)

Comment: Just change the value in the DropDownListBox and stay on the form. There is still the TextArea value for the user to fill in.

Comment: You're telling the browser to submit the form on a change, and then ask us how to stop this :) remove the line that submits it: $('form#myForm').submit();

Comment: I don't understand what your wanting to do. When your select an option, the value is changed, so why are you handling the change event in order to change itself? Whats the purpose of the script?

Comment: I know I am confused. Depending on the value selected in the Drop Down, I want to change what might be displayed before it.

Comment: The script is wrong. I want to get the value of the selected item and potentially change what is displayed below it before the user submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onsubmit to the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {id = "myForm", onsubmit="return CheckForm()}))
```

Then add a javascript function to see if everything is filled in:

```
function CheckForm() {
    var ret = true;
    if (document.getElementById("DropDownListForId").selectedIndex == 0) {
        ret = false;
    }
    // Add whatever other logic or checks you need
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Its doing that behavior now. The JavaScript function is an OnChange handler that submits the form.Can I do it without submitting the form?

Comment: Ok. Do you have a DIV or something that you are going to display that "the list has been changed"?

Answer (score 0):

In short - it sounds like you want the normal behaviour of a dropdown list (or select). So remove the javascript, and it will work as you expect, no?

As to the comment - getting value and text. You're failing to tell us WHERE you want to display this. "Before" is not enough. Try this javascript instead, and perhaps you can make edits to suit your need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('#DropDownListForId').change(function () {
            alert('This is the selected value: ' + $(this).val() + ' and text: ' + $("option:selected", $(this)).text());
            //this should, hopefully, update the label with the current selected text. I doubt this is wanted, but it shows what could be done.
            $(this).parent().find('label').html($("option:selected", $(this)).text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The script is wrong. I want to get the value of the selected item and potentially change what is displayed below it before the user submits the form.